# Как из url получить параметры?

Tags: python

Есть ссылка:

```
google.com/news?page=1&perpage=20
```

Как получить из этого url список параметров:

```
['page=1', 'perpage=20']
```

Comment: отсечь по ?, разделить по &

Comment: А почему бы не воспользоваться [стандартным парсером параметров](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)?

Comment: @Эникейщик Лучше не надо ручного колхоза советовать, когда есть стандартные библиотеки )  Даже если это и работает правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покажу как воспользоваться предложенным в комментариях `urllib.parse`

```py
from urllib import parse
url = "google.com/news?page=1&perpage=20"

all_instances = parse.urlparse(url)
```

Переменная `all_instances` будет содержать все сущности, которые присутствуют в ссылке

```
>>> print(all_instances)
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='google.com/news', params='', query='page=1&perpage=20', fragment='')
```

Теперь можно обратиться к параметру `query` и получить необходимый данные

```py
query = all_instances.query
```

и распарсить значения

```py
dict_from_query = parse.parse_qs(query) # Здесь будет словарь 
list_from_query = parse.parse_qsl(query) # Здесь будет список

print(f"Словарь = {dict_from_query}, список = {list_from_query}" )
# out
# Словарь = {'page': ['1'], 'perpage': ['20']}, список = [('page', '1'), ('perpage', '20')]
```

Либо к виду, который вы указали

```py
list_from_query = query.split("&")

print(list_from_query)

#out 
# ['page=1', 'perpage=20']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_parameter
parms = []
url = "google.com/news?page=1&perpage=20"
parms.append(url_query_parameter(url, 'page'))
parms.append(url_query_parameter(url, 'perpage'))
print(parms)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: т.е. сначала нужно посмотреть названия параметров и вручную добавить их в код?

Comment: ну да, логично)